# Laravel Kernel load dynamic middleware array

Tags: laravel

want edit my Kernel.php file and disabled some Middleware in on place in aplication (I want my header response was shortly, [here is my stack subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52621615/laravel-nginx-customize-header-request))

I have some idea but i don't know what is the next step:

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    public function __construct(Application $app, Router $router)
    {
        $url = \Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()->url();
        if($url == 'http://autoservie.test/save'){

           //HERE i want set  protected $middlewareGroup and remove session 
           middleware from 'web'

        }else{

          // HERE set another protected $middlewareGroup

        }

        parent::__construct($app, $router);
    }

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

The question is, how set dynamic protected $middlewareGroups array in constructor? Or is there any other solution ?

Comment: Looks like a bad practice to set/unset different middleware groups based on the route. Why not just assign the middleware to the routes you need and take them off global middleware? Or create a custom middlewareGroup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like

```
    $index = array_search(\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, $middlewareGroups['web']);
    unset($middlewareGroups['web'][$index]);
```